# Update UTableView dataSource during UITableView reloading already

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, datasource

I have UITableView with some sections with some different rows. And during my flow, I have to make several network calls, and when I get the response I want to update my table view. The problem is - I have no idea when I'll get the next response, so sometimes I'm trying to update the data source (make changes with models of cells) and then reload updated sections/cells, when UITableView reloading data already, then the application crashes.
Sure I can use tableView.reloadData to safely refresh the view, but I wonder - is there a solution to updating UITableView using methods like reloadCells / insertRows / deleteRows in my case?

Comment: You should use [`performBatchUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates) to make your changes to the table at the same time as you change your data source.

Answer (score 1):

If you are either updating your table view or its data model from a background thread, don't do that. That is likely to crash your app. All updates to UI objects like table views need to happen on the main thread.

If you're talking about changing your data model and telling the table view about adding/removing rows, then use `performBatchUpdates` as @PaulW11 suggests

Comment: Ok, let see that case:
I've received first response, starting modify models of my rows and then inserting/deleting/reloading cells in view using 'performBatchUpdates'.
But in same time (before first portion of data was handled) I've received second response, what to do then?

Comment: Deliver the changes in batches. Change your data model and tell the table view about the updates in a call to `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)`. Don't issue another update until the completion handler of the previous call to `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` is called.

Comment: I think I got the point, thanks a lot